# toggleClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I cant get toggleClass to work, here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/V6VHX/

clicking on the image is supposed to make the text change colour by removing the .mid class but its not doing anything at the moment.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image").click(function(){
        $("p").toggleClass(".mid");
    });
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p>HELLO</p>
        <p class="mid">HELLO</p>
        <img id="image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artua/mac/512/Earth-icon.png"/>
    </div>   
</div>
```

The css is basically just saying the .mid class is red text, if you need it see the jsFiddle,

what am i missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With toggleClass, the leading dot before the class name is not required.

```
$("p").toggleClass("mid");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the '.' prefixing 'mid'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#image").click(function () {
    $(this).prev('p').toggleClass("mid");
});
```

1. No need of `.` inside the toggleClass method.